# aggregating jsonarray into Map<key, list> in spark in spark2.x

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am quite new to Spark. I have a input json file which I am reading as

```
val df = spark.read.json("/Users/user/Desktop/resource.json");
```

Contents of resource.json looks like this:

```
{"path":"path1","key":"key1","region":"region1"}
{"path":"path112","key":"key1","region":"region1"}
{"path":"path22","key":"key2","region":"region1"}
```

Is there any way we can process this dataframe and aggregate result as

```
Map<key, List<data>>
```

where data is each json object in which key is present.

For ex: expected result is

```
Map<key1 =[{"path":"path1","key":"key1","region":"region1"}, {"path":"path112","key":"key1","region":"region1"}] ,
key2 = [{"path":"path22","key":"key2","region":"region1"}]>
```

Any reference/documents/link to proceed further would be a great help.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use groupBy in scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.read
case class cC(path: String, key: String, region: String)

val df = spark.read.json("/Users/user/Desktop/resource.json");

scala> df.show
+----+-------+-------+
| key|   path| region|
+----+-------+-------+
|key1|  path1|region1|
|key1|path112|region1|
|key2| path22|region1|
+----+-------+-------+
//Please note that original json structure is gone. Use .toJSON to get json back and extract key from json and create RDD[(String, String)] RDD[(key, json)]

val rdd = df.toJSON.rdd.map(m => {
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val parsedObj = read[cC](m)
(parsedObj.key, m)
})

scala> rdd.collect.groupBy(_._1).map(m => (m._1,m._2.map(_._2).toList))
res39: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(key2 -> List({"key":"key2","path":"path22","region":"region1"}), key1 -> List({"key":"key1","path":"path1","region":"region1"}, {"key":"key1","path":"path112","region":"region1"}))
```

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for. Thank you @hadooper.

Comment: If an answer has resolved your issue, kindly accept it - see What should I do when someone answers my question?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupBy` with `collect_list`, which is an aggregation function that collects all matching values into a list per key.

Notice that the original JSON strings are already "gone" (Spark parses them into individual columns), so if you really want a list of all *records* (with all their columns, including the key), you can use the `struct` function to combine columns into one column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

df.groupBy($"key")
  .agg(collect_list(struct($"path", $"key", $"region")) as "value")
```

The result would be:

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
|key |value                                             |
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
|key1|[[path1, key1, region1], [path112, key1, region1]]|
|key2|[[path22, key2, region1]]                         |
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
```