# How to group certain column, and fetch the whole row as a JSON String in Scala Spark?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to collect a dataset in JSON format

```
val df = spark.sql("select invn_ctl_nbr,cl_id,department from pi_prd.table1 where batch_run_dt='20190101' and batchid = '20190101001' limit 10").toJSON.rdd
```

The generated result is in the format of Array[String]:

```
Array({"invn_ctl_nbr":"1","cl_id":"AK","department":"Dept1"}
{"invn_ctl_nbr":"2","cl_id":"AF","department":"Dept1"}
{"invn_ctl_nbr":"3","cl_id":"AF","department":"Dept2"}
{"invn_ctl_nbr":"4","cl_id":"AK","department":"Dept3"})
```

Further, I am trying to group the data in such a way they it should provide me an the result in the below format:

```
Map<key, List<data>>
```

To give an example:

```
Map<AK=[{"invn_ctl_nbr":"1","cl_id":"AK","department":"Dept1"},{"invn_ctl_nbr":"4","cl_id":"AK","department":"Dept3"}],AF=[{"invn_ctl_nbr":"2","cl_id":"AF","department":"Dept1"},{"invn_ctl_nbr":"3","cl_id":"AF","department":"Dept2"}]>
```

I have already tried a solution provided in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915562/aggregating-jsonarray-into-mapkey-list-in-spark-in-spark2-x). The code I used to fetched the required result was:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.read

case class cC(invn_ctl_nbr: String,cl_id: String,department: String)

val rdd_new = df.map(m => {
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val parsedObj = read[cC](m)
(parsedObj.srk_clm_id, m)
})

rdd_new.collect.groupBy(_._1).map(m => (m._1,m._2.map(_._2).toList))
```

but it's giving me below error:

```
org.json4s.package$MappingException: Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor
args=
arg types=
constructor=public cC($iw,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

My mapping is correct for what I have specified in the case class and what is coming in from the rdd, not sure what exactly I am missing here. Can anybody please help in resolving this?, would be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` with `struct`, `to_json` and `collect_list` to get the result you wanted

The dataframe `df` here is equivalent as your `spark.sql("select query")`

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1", "AK", "Dept1"),
  ("2", "AF", "Dept1"),
  ("3", "AF", "Dept2"),
  ("4", "AK", "Dept3")
).toDF("invn_ctl_nbr","cl_id","department")


val result = df.groupBy($"cl_id")
  .agg(to_json(collect_list(struct(df.columns.map(col(_)) : _*))))
  .rdd.map(x => (x.getString(0), x.get(1))).collectAsMap()
```

Output (result):

```
Map(AF -> [{"invn_ctl_nbr":"2","cl_id":"AF","department":"Dept1"},{"invn_ctl_nbr":"3","cl_id":"AF","department":"Dept2"}], AK -> [{"invn_ctl_nbr":"1","cl_id":"AK","department":"Dept1"},{"invn_ctl_nbr":"4","cl_id":"AK","department":"Dept3"}])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for helping here. Actually the data is being stored in parquet format. In that context, how can we modify the above code please?

Comment: @MohitRaja Create a dataframe by reading parquet as `val df = spark.read.parquet("path of parquet file ").select("invn_ctl_nbr","cl_id","department")`

Comment: yes that's right, I was actually thinking to handle this parquet file as an rdd, never did that before. `val df = spark.sql("select invn_ctl_nbr,cl_id,department from pi_prd.table1 where batch_run_dt='20190101' and batchid = '20190101001' limit 10")` itself worked there. Thanks! a ton again